# Displaying the name of each object

Tags: c#, json, object

I'm creating software where the users can create and load profiles to fill textboxes. The names and other information contained in the profile are stored in a JSON file. A profile name can contain any text that is entered by the user.
So for this, I'm trying to get each objects names of the JSON file (= each profile name) to display them in a treeview, but all I get is their contents.

I have a JSON file containing two objects:

```
[
    {
        "profile1": {
            //Some informations 1
        },
        "profile2": {
            //Some informations 2
        }
    }
]
```

For now, I have code that allows me to get the value of a given tag, but I can't find a way to get the name of each objects:

```
using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText(path))
                {
                    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                    dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                    foreach (var item in array)
                    {
                        debug_tb.Text += item.profile1; //Gives me each values of the "profile1 object"
                    }

                }
```

So what I'm trying to get is to display "profile1" and "profile2" and "profile3" if it exists.

Comment: Your file contains an array of one object with two properties. I suggest changing that so that it is just the object with two properties, then iterate over the properties.

Comment: So the JSON file should looks like ```{
 "profile1": {
  //...
 },
 "profile2": {
  //...
 }
}``` ?

Comment: Dont focus on what the interim JSON should look like. Create a class that is easy to work with and has the data you need.  Serialize it - it will deserialize back into the same class.  *Dat be how dey do*

Comment: Is it possible for you to change your JSON format or is it a fix format? I can show you an easy example when you can can change the JSON format. If not, then it is also possible, but a little tricky.

Comment: @skipper Sure I can change it

Comment: Do you need to have keys like profile1 profile2 etc? Why dont you have just array of json objects, where one json object represents one profile?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your JSON is an array with one object. So you can simplefy the JSON first:

```
{
    "profile1": {
        //Some informations 1
    },
    "profile2": {
        //Some informations 2
    }
}
```

Then you can easyly iterate over every item in the JSON and get the `Name` of it

```
    dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ \"profile1\": { }, \"profile2\": { } }");
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        debug_tb.Text += item.Name; //Gives the name of the object
    }
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Ok, so the property I was looking for was Name. Ok ! Thanks a lot, I changed the JSON format as well

Comment: I have another pb : I can't change the format... So now there is an array containing every objects (profiles). So I named a tag "profile_name" to list them all on the load of the form in the treeview, but I can't find a way to list them all

Comment: If you can't change the JSON than keep it like in your Question *[{ "profile1": { }, "profile2": { } }]* and change your loop to iterate the first element (It has only one element) `foreach (var item in array.First)`